# Kotlin run a task for at most fixed time

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there a way to run a task in Kotlin for at most a fixed amount of time?
For example something like:

```
    val result: XXX? = runAtMostFor(millis = 1000) { ..TRY to do something }
```

The goal would be to immediately have the result if the task ends before the 1000 millis, or just a null value and to stop doing the task when the deadline comes

Answer (score 4):

You can use [withTimeout](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html) or [withTimeoutOrNull](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout-or-null.html)

Answer (score 0):

`withTimeout` doesn't work if you are doing blocking operation inside. For example, the following code will print "wrong"

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*;
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        withTimeout(500) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            println("wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

There is no way to run blocking code with timeout. Only way would be to modify the code itself to periodically check if it's time to stop.